# Xtext & Xtend - Determine if the parameter type is a Java data type or not

Tags: java, xtext, xtend

I have a section in my grammar like the following

```
Type:
    '(' parameter=Param ':' dataType=DataType ')'
;

DataType :
    javaType = JvmTypeReference | ModelResource
;

ModelResource :
    name=ID
;
```

In the corresponding xtend, I had to determine if javaType is one of the primitive java types or a user defined class.

I tried the following check

```
if (type.dataType instanceof ModelResource) {
  ...
}
```

I provide in the execution as follows

```
(user : UserResource)
(id : Long)
```

But according to the condition, the dataType `user` is an instance of JvmTypeReference and not of ModelResource type.

How can I change the grammar/condition in order to identify `user` is not of Java Type and `id` is of Java Type?

Comment: this wont work at all cause your grammar is ambigous